# ReactJS Material UI Drawer Display Issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-navigation-drawer

I used the Material UI API for Drawer (found [here](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/)) to create a sidebar component. However, when I render this component on a screen along with other components, it is displayed under the other components as shown below :

[image]

I tried to add an elevation property, hoping it would resolve the issue, but that didn't work. Is there a way to overcome this? Here is the code:

```
const drawerWidth = '224px';

interface propsDashBoard {
  itemsBeforeDivider: ItemData[]; 
}

interface ItemData {
  name: string; 
  Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>;
  routeAddress: string; 
}

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    position: 'relative', 
    backgroundColor: COLOR.NEUTRAL.WHITE,
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
      position: 'absolute', 
      zIndex: -1,
      boxShadow: '0px 1px 1px red', 
    },
  },
  appBar: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      //width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      margin: '0px',
      backgroundColor: COLOR.NEUTRAL.WHITE,
      // position: 'absolute', 
      boxShadow:'0px 1px 0px #DBE1E7', 
    },
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    display: 'none',
    backgroundColor: COLOR.NEUTRAL.WHITE,
    },
  },
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    paddingLeft: '33px', 
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  cssBaseline: {
    boxShadow:'none', 
  },
  navBar: {
backgroundColor: COLOR.NEUTRAL.WHITE,
  }, 

}));

    const MyDrawer =(props: propsDashBoard) => {
      const {
        itemsBeforeDivider,
      } = props; 
      const classes = useStyles();
      const theme = useTheme();
      const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
    
      const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
      };
    
      return (
        <Router history={history}>
          <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
            <Drawer 
                variant="temporary" 
                anchor ={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
                open={mobileOpen}
                onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
                classes={{
                      paper: classes.drawerPaper
                    }}
                ModalProps={{
                      keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
                    }}
        >
          <div>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} /> 
            <Divider />
            <List>
              {itemsBeforeDivider.map(({name, Icon, routeAddress}) => (
                <ListItem button key={name} component={Link} to={routeAddress}>
                  <ListItemIcon><Icon /></ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={name} />
    
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
    
          </div>
        </Drawer> 
    
        <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
        <div>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} /> 
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {itemsBeforeDivider.map(({name, Icon, routeAddress}) => (
            <ListItem button key={name} component={Link} to={routeAddress}>
              <ListItemIcon><Icon /></ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}

        </List>
        <Divider /> 
      </div>
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        </nav>
      </Router> 
  ); 
 
}

const WhiteTypography = withStyles({
root: {
  backgroundColor: COLOR.NEUTRAL.WHITE,
  variant:"h6", 
  noWrap:"true", 
}
})(Typography); 

function DashBoard (props: propsDashBoard) {
  const {
    itemsBeforeDivider,
  } = props; 
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };



return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline classes={classes.cssBaseline} />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <MyDrawer itemsBeforeDivider={itemsBeforeDivider}/>
        
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trying giving drawerWidth value like 150 or so and don't give value in pixel.